# Compressed Population Complexity in Minimum Description Length (MDL)

Tags: model-selection, information-theory

I am studying the MDL and found it is sum of model complexity and compressed population complexity. To my understanding, model complexity refers to number of bits to encode the model, which can be computed by number of bits per sample (i.e. log N) multiply by number of permutations. On the other hand, the compressed population complexity is the number of data its can compressed. However, it is usually estimated by the average number of bits for encoding the data multiply by the number of population (i.e. N), which can be computed by a entropy function.

However, can anyone help me to understand how can the compressed population complexity can be estimated by the average no. of bits for data encoding.